# What causes the use of a function to cause a difference on the android canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas

So, for starters, I'm learning canvas by expanding upon: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-1.

I figured that I wanted to make my program run something everytime it runs, so I decided to add a function to be ran in the run function, so it looks like:

```
public void run() {

Canvas c;

while (_run) {

displayHumanHand();

c = null;

try {

                    c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {

                        onDraw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

With displayhumanhand just having an array of "cards" and arranging them numerically, and should have no effect on the bitmaps being used (for now).  However, the difference that adding this line of code causes to the quality changes it from:

[image]

Why?  What causes the decrease in quality?  How can I fix this?
Also, why does the image on the right look different from the one on the left when I am drawing the same icon (For the first imgur link)?

Answer (score 0):

Bleugh. That code isn't so good in the tutorial. It's doing so many things wrong I don't know where to start, but a tight infinite loop being one of them. Follow this tutorial instead: http://blog.goltergaul.de/2010/03/android-game-project-basics-of-threads-and-canvas/